# How do assign a value to a variable from the result of a select statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables

```
SELECT TOP 1 [FirstName], [LastName]
FROM [table]

DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(25)
```

After I run the query above, I want to assign [FirstName] that is brought back from the query to @firstName.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(25) 

SELECT TOP 1 @firstName = [FirstName] FROM [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(25), @LastName VARCHAR(25)

SELECT TOP 1 @firstName = [FirstName], @LastName = [LastName]
FROM [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259193%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to assign a value from a query:

```
DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(25)

SET @firstName = (SELECT TOP 1 [FirstName] FROM [table])
```